# Call function from another class (Odoo13)

Tags: python, odoo

I want to call same function from another class-object. I try this but doesn't work.Any help please.

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.a'
        def action_button(self):
              ......
        }

class ClassB(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.b'
    def call_func_b(self):
        self.env["class.b"].action_button()

 <button name="call_func_b" type="object" string="Create Action b"/>


class ClassC(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.c'
    def call_func_c(self):
        self.env["class.c"].action_button()

 <button name="call_func_c" type="object" string="Create Action c"/>
```

Comment: I think you want your ClassB to inherit from CalssA.. `class ClassB(ClassA)` and then `def call_func_b(self): return self.action_button()`

Comment: Use the `ClassA` model reference to call `action_buton` method: `def call_func_b(self): return self.env["class.a"].action_button()`

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is that you can consider ClassA as base/parent class and inherit it in both ClassB and ClassC. Hence, you will be able to access ClassA's attributes and methods from its child classes, that is, ClassB and ClassC.

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.a'
    def action_button(self):
              ......
        }

class ClassB(ClassA):
    _name = 'class.b'
    def call_func_b(self):
        self.action_button()

 <button name="call_func_b" type="object" string="Create Action b"/>


class ClassC(ClassA):
    _name = 'class.c'
    def call_func_c(self):
        self.action_button()

 <button name="call_func_c" type="object" string="Create Action c"/>
```

Alternatively, you can define the `action_button` method as a static method.

```
@staticmethod
def action_button():
```

Now, you will be able to use this method by calling `ClassA.action_button()` from any class.

Comment: with the second method , although the function is executed, but there is no function return of action_button  with type 'ir.actions.act_window'. @Shivam Gera

Answer (score 1):

```
class ClassA(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.a'
    @api.model
    def action_button(self):
          # you can return action here if you want
          return action
     }

class ClassB(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.b'
    def call_func_b(self):
        #use return to pass data to client;
        #env["class.a"] finds model with provided name, you used same same models name 
        return self.env["class.a"].action_button()

 <button name="call_func_b" type="object" string="Create Action b"/>


class ClassC(models.Model):
    _name = 'class.c'
    def call_func_c(self):
        return self.env["class.a"].action_button()

<button name="call_func_c" type="object" string="Create Action c"/>
```